# Django Custom Form Validation IP address and Domain name

Tags: python, django

Im just writing a form. However I want to perform custom validation on the `hostname`. That `if type = A` then validate that it is a domain name other wise if it is `type = PTR` validate it is an `IP addres`s. Would this logic be done within the form or the view ?

```
RECORD_CHOICES = (
     ('A','A'),
     ('Cname','CNAME'),
     ('PTR', 'PTR'),
    )

class CacheCheck(forms.Form):
    type = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=formfields.TYPE_CHOICES, initial='FIXED')
    record = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=formfields.RECORD_CHOICES, initial='FIXED')
    hostname = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    def clean(self):  
        cleaned_data = super(CacheCheck, self).clean()
        record = cleaned_data.get("record")

        if record == "PTR":
            hostname = forms.GenericIPAddressField(label=("ip address"))
        else record == "A":
            hostname = forms.RegexField(label=("hostname"), max_length=31, regex=r'[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}'
```

Also the forms.Form that is passed to the CacheCheck class is this a form of mixin or subclassing ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write a `clean()` method for your form. See the Django docs on [cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) for more information.

Your `clean` method should return the cleaned_data dictionary. Inside the cleaned method, you cannot instantiate new form fields, but you can validators.

```
from django.core.validators import validate_ipv46_address, RegexValidator

validate_hostname = RegexValidator(regex=r'[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}')

def clean(self):  
    cleaned_data = super(CacheCheck, self).clean()
    record = cleaned_data.get("record")
    hostname = cleaned_data.get(hostname, "")

    if record == "PTR":
        validate_ipv46_address(hostname)
    elif record == "A":
        validate_hostname(hostname)
        # todo: check length of hostname as well

    return cleaned_data
```

To answer your other question, your `CacheCheck` class is a subclass of `forms.Form`.

Comment: ok cool. So if I needed the same function clean self throughout all my forms what would you suggest would be the best method so I 'DRY' :o) Thanks for all your help for far...

Comment: If you have a model, you can put the validation in the model's [clean](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method, and all model forms will use it. Otherwise, use inheritence. Create a form with the clean method and subclass it when you need that validation.

Comment: Thanks. I still have one remaining issue but I have not posted this within http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105947/how-do-you-pass-a-validation-error-to-a-template-in-django

Answer (score -1):

*Would this logic be done within the form or the view ?*

Both places. Validate in javascript on the client-side to avoid dumb mistakes taxing your server resources. Then validate on the server-side to avoid having bad data in your db.

*Form that is passed to the CacheCheck class is this a form of mixin or subclassing?*

This is a form of subclassing. CacheCheck inherits Form.