# Add Validation Error message to rendered template in Django (via views.py)

Tags: python, django, validation

I've written a validation that checks to make sure a certain number of images are uploaded before the user can move on to another view.  I know that the validation works, because I have successfully redirected them back to the upload page if they don't have enough images and to the preview page if they do.

CODE

```
@login_required
def preview_website(request, slug):
    student = Student.objects.get(slug=slug)

    if student.studentimage_set.filter(image_type="portrait").exists() and
student.studentimage_set.filter(image_type="interest1").exists() and 
student.studentimage_set.filter(image_type="interest2").exists() and 
student.studentimage_set.filter(image_type="interest3").exists():
        return render(request, 'students/preview_website.html', {
            'student': student,
        })
    else:
        return redirect('upload_student_image', slug=student.slug)
```

The issue I'm having now is the notification of the error.  I would like to let them know that they need to add more images in order to move forward.  Is there a way, **through views.py**, to print a notification at the top of the template? (I know it is more standard to use validation in the forms or models, but this is a special case.)

I've tried the following, but I get an error page with no clean way back to the image upload page:

```
    else:
        raise ValidationError("Please make sure you have uploaded 4 images!")
```

I also tried the following, but I didn't see anything printed on the template page:

```
    else:
        msg = "Please make sure you have uploaded 4 images!"
```

I've already read through: [17105947](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105947/how-to-you-pass-a-validation-error-to-a-template), but the solution didn't work for me.

Any ideas?  I'm pretty new to programming and Django, so I hope this is just a small oversight on my part and a relatively easy fix!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the error message in your template behind an if scope.

In your view:

```
@login_required
def preview_website(request, slug):
    student = Student.objects.get(slug=slug)

    if student.studentimage_set.filter(image_type="portrait").exists() and
student.studentimage_set.filter(image_type="interest1").exists() and 
student.studentimage_set.filter(image_type="interest2").exists() and 
student.studentimage_set.filter(image_type="interest3").exists():
        return render(request, 'students/preview_website.html', {
            'student': student})
    else:
        error_message = "Please make sure you have uploaded 4 images!" 
        return render(request, 'students/preview_website.html', {
            'student': student, 'error_message': error_message})
```

Add this to the top of your template

```
{% if error_message %}
  <p>{{ error_message }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I remembered it differently for some reason, but I just verified that using only `if` works as expected.

Comment: Thank you!  I don't have enough reputation to upvote this, but it's exactly what I was trying to do.  Is there any documentation I can read to better understand this for next time?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by doing

```
length(request.FILES)
```

in view and if length is less than what you want you can return to upload html

```
return render_to_response('upload.html',{'error':error},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In html page use following style you can show error

```
{% if error %}
    {{ error }}
{% endif%}
```